# Why does my code freeze when using for loop but not specified number loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, while-loop

I figured it out but it sure took me 4 hours. It never caused any errors so I used the debug feature which wasn't much help. Since there was no error I'm unsure what else to look up before I ask my question.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i+7) { //30:00
        var random_x = getRandomInt(0, width-1);
        var random_y = getRandomInt(0, height-1);
        var sample_color = img.colorAt(random_x, random_y);
```

`Solution:` change `i+7`to `i++`

I'm still confused on why `i+7` works when number of loops are specified but not when ran with infinity loop.

Comment: You need to assign the incremented value back to the variable: `i += 7`. With your approach, you've effectively created an infinite loop because the value of `i` never changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you aren't assigning the value to `i` again.

When you write `i++` you basically write a shorthand version of `i = i + 1`. In your code you write `i + 7` which doesn't do anything and basically is an infinite loop. You should have written `i = i + 7` to assign a new value to `i` (or `i += 7` for the shorthand version).

Answer (score 1):

either  use   `i=i+7` or `i+=7`

`i=i+7` means you are changing the value of `i` by adding `7` to it. So after every increment value of `i` increment by `7`.

For better knowledge, refer assignment operators.

Comment: Okay that clears up some, but i'm still confused on why `i+7` works with a numbered loop without rewritting `i = i + 7`

Comment: you are not assigning/incrementing the value i+7 to i, if you want to increment the value you need to assign the = (equal)operator